# ryzen 2600X speccy temps really high temps

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, overheating, amd-ryzen

Speccy says my cpu temp is around 100 degrees! While AMD master and CoreTemp are saying it is about 49 degrees? Should I be worried, should I do something about it? I now have nzxt s340 with stock fans and a Ryzen 2600X with stock fan. I was thinking about adding a fan, or is it maybe something with the thermal paste?

I'm probally woried for no reason(hopefully)
Click for screenshots.

Speccy
[image]

AMD Master
[image]

CoreTemp
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When 2 apps tell you one thing, 1 one tells you another, unless you have compelling reasons to believe the outlier, then don't.

Given the information you have given us, there is no reason to believe there is anything wrong with your computer and you should NOT go about trying to "fix" what isn't broken.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry about, Speccy does not report accurately on the Ryzen 2XXX chips.

Maybe their paid version does?  I wouldn't know :)  AMD master utility is accurate, so just use that.